# Spring Security 403 error when access with role JAVA

Tags: java, spring

All users can login successfully but all of them can open only url which are using **permitAll()** method. FOr url meta i have set the role "RADMIN" and after the user with that role is logged in he can not open meta or any other url because of **403 ERROR**. The url which can be open are only "login", "logout", "home".

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("bg.package")
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SpringSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationService authenticationService;

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/assets/**");
    }

@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/login", "/home", "/logout").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("meta/**").hasAuthority("RADMIN")
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and().addFilterAfter(new CsrfHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class);
}

@Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        Md5PasswordEncoder encoder = new Md5PasswordEncoder();
        auth.userDetailsService(authenticationService).passwordEncoder(encoder);
    }
}
```

**AuthService**

```
@Service
public class AuthenticationService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private AuthDao authDao;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        AuthModel authModel = authDao.getUserInfo(email);
        GrantedAuthority authority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority(authModel.getRank());
        UserDetails userDetails = (UserDetails) new User(authModel.getName(), authModel.getPass(), Arrays.asList(authority));
        return userDetails;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are checking the role of a user with `hasAuthority()` method you should also include prefix `ROLE_` before your role name. So the part of your security configuration which checks for role should look like this:

```
.antMatchers("meta/**").hasAuthority("ROLE_RADMIN")
```

Alternatively instead of `hasAuthority("ROLE_RADMIN")` you can use `hasRole("RADMIN")`.

Comment: What is `authModel.getRank()` returning? For the solution I've gave you this  should work if `authModel.getRank()` returns `ROLE_RADMIN`. In case it returns `RADMIN` they the code you've written should be fine (part with `hasAuthority("RADMIN")`.
From the code written above I cannot tell what can be wrong. Try to debug and see what `authModel.getRank()` is returning.

Comment: authModel.getRank() returns ROLE_RADMIN. I tested it with hard coded value and it works correct. Now i found the problem but i do not know how to fix it.... it is that this method **loadUserByUsername** is not invoked and i do not know how to do that.

Comment: This method is only called when authenticating the user. It means you first need to login so that the security context of a user is saved in the session.
After that is should all work fine. Anyway you need to figure this out. And with the change provided in my answer you won't receive `403` anymore.
Check this setup for simple HTTP BASIC authentication: http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/jc.html#jc-httpsecurity

Comment: Thank you. I will try to debug it again.